# Content type 'application/merge-patch+json' not supported when using spring webclient

Tags: spring, http, webclient, patch

using spring webclient to make http call. But found no MediaType defined for `application/merge-patch+json`. Anyway I hard injected the header Content-Type by `headers.add("Content-Type", "application/merge-patch+json");` or `.contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/merge-patch+json"))`. Got same runtime error `Content type 'application/merge-patch+json' not supported for bodyType=com.test.Account`

I think the webclient block the call. Suggest to have a compatible way to not check headers.